# Does jvm free the thread's stack when the thread terminates

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I run the following program on my machine and on a customer's machine with jvm parameter `-Xmx1024m`.

```
int i=0;
while(true)
{
  new Thread().start();
  i++;
}
```

Both machines have `windows 7` and `jdk 7 32bits`.

On my machine I terminated the process when the i was around 3M. On the customer's machine the program threw an `OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native Thread` when the i was around 8K.

I retried the experiment with jvm parameter `-Xmx24m`. In this case the program on customer's machine threw the same error when the i was around 24K. There is also a small increment if i reduce the thread's stack trace to  128K with `-Xss`.

It seems like the customer's machine does not free the thread's stack when the thread terminates.

Has anyone met this issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are relying on the minute details of how fast the threads are started and subsequently die. On one machine the thread generation process overruns the thread death process, on another it happens to do otherwise. Your counter only keeps track of the total number of threads created, not the net number of threads in existence at any point in time.

Main point: your test code isn't helpful at proving anything important about the runtimes.

Comment: The above code was just for the experiment. The real application creates 2-3 threads per seconds, so the real application takes some hours until it throws the OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native Thread. I don't try to count the maximum number of concurrent threads but to understand why my application throws exception on the customer's machine.

Comment: Your application's problem is that the threads never die. It has nothing to do with the inability of the JVM to release the resources of the dead threads.

Comment: What do you mean with "the threads never die" ? What should I call to kill the threads ?

Comment: When the thread's `run` method completes, the thread dies. Your `run` methods do not complete. I cannot know why.

Answer (score 1):

`OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native Thread`

Usually implies you have created more threads than the OS allows, not necessarily you are running out of thread stack space.  I would put a yield/sleep after each creation to allow the OS to catch up.

Comment: @John Vint Your answer is a special case of a more general principle:  Threads that release any given resource should be given priority over threads that want to grab the same resource.

Comment: @Bathsheba for what purpose?

Comment: I just don't know what that proves, we can assume it starts.

Comment: @jameslarge The only point I make is that starting more threads than the OS allows (and having run) will throw this exception, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the second sentence in your answer where you suggested calling Thread.yield().  That effectively is the same as lowering the priority of the main thread (i.e., it allows the other threads to run.)  The main Thread in the example is grabbing resources (native threads), and the other Threads are releasing them.  Giving the other Threads priority over the main Thread prevents the resource from being depleted.

Comment: @jameslarge the thread resource isn't being depleted.  It's the OS resource.  If the OS has a limit of 1000 threads and I start 1001 threads, regardless of memory per thread, it will still throw an OOM error.

Comment: Yes! Exactly!  If the OS has a limit of 1000 native threads, then native threads are a scarce resource.  Every time the main thread in the example creates a new suicide thread, it consumes one unit of that resource.  Every time one a suicide thread achieves its mission, it releases one unit of the resource.  The OOM is thrown if the resource is exhausted, but giving priority to the suicide threads prevents that from happening.  The same general principle applies whether we are talking about native threads, file handles, ports, memory, disk space, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the customer's machine does not free the thread's stack when the thread terminates.

It may or may not.  This depends on when the thread actually goes out of scope and when the GC runs.  Also, the JVM may not necessarily decide to immediately reap the thread stack memory because it may want to try to reuse the thread instead of fragmenting core by releasing it to another part of the JVM.  The stack space for threads actually is most likely reserved for threads to use so this is more about concurrent active (or dormant) threads and reuse of them as opposed to freeing memory.

If you are starting so many threads I'd recommend using an fixed number of threads `ExecutorService` so you can have more control over the precise number of threads that are started.  Otherwise you are at the whim of the JVM and the GC.